# Correct learning algorithm for grouped examples

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms

I need to learn which item will be (most probably) picked from a group. The data I have consists of groups by 10 items and which one was picked(or if neither was picked).

My current approach is to ignore the groups and to use flat list with all items classified as picked or not picked and use some classification algorithm, but I wanted to know if there is a way to use the knowledge that the item was picked from that specific group.

Comment: A couple of questions:
1- Group size is always 10 ?
2- How many items are there in general ?

Comment: Group size is always the same(10 for now, but can change). There are 1000s of groups in the dataset.

Comment: Ok, but given a group of size 10, how are the 10 items selected? I assume they must be drawn from a larger set. How large is that set? Can there be duplicates in the groups ? For example, you're building groups of 10 letters and you want to know which letter is likely to be drawn...Are you using letters from A to Z ? Do you have groups with duplicate letters ?

Comment: The group items are drawn at random. The items are 8 dimensional vectors. I am searching for general learning algorithm for such class of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the size of each group. You want to learn the function $f$ that takes $M$ vectors $v_{i}$, $i \in [1,M]$  and yields a vector $\hat{v}$ that can be 0 or one of the $v_{i}$.
You can train a DNN to learn $f$ by organizing your training data as follows:

```
Input              Label
[batchSize, M, 1]  [batchSize,1]
```

Optimize on the reduced RMS error between the predicted vectors and the label vectors. The group information will then be learned by your DNN.